# Opacity of dragging UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, opacity

I am working on an application where buttons can be dragged around.

My problem is, that while dragging, the opacity is very low and the button is nearly invisible. I did not find out yet what I have to set so it stays the same as when non-dragged.

I set the targets to drag&drop as follows:

```
dragButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(whileDragging), for: .touchDragInside)
dragButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(afterDragging), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And the whileDragging function to show what I tried:

```
@objc private func whileDragging(sender: AnyObject, event: UIEvent) {
    guard let control = sender as? UIControl else { return }
    guard let touches = event.allTouches else { return }
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    let draggingButton = sender as! UIButton

    // Does nothing
    draggingButton.layer.opacity = 1
    draggingButton.alpha = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the UIButton's type to 'Custom' in Interface Builder. This will stop the fading effect when it is held.

Comment: That's nearly it. The text now stays solid, but the BackgroundImage still gets opacity, can I prevent that?

Comment: try `draggingButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false`

Comment: That did the trick, I set that property in my viewDidLoad and now it seems to work as expected, thank you!